# failed cast to "AIControllet type" Bluprint class

Tags: casting, unreal-engine4

In ue4[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Axkcy.png), I've created a blueprint class from AIController and then another Blueprint class from character. However, when I try to cast my character controller into AIC_Enemy (name of the class derived by AIController) this fails. I'm sending also the pictures with the content of the two classes. Please let me know if you need additional information. In the two images, I'm showing the content of interest of the two classes

Comment: can you send the class with the cast

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue. In the pawn setting of the enemy I created I had to put as AI Controller type the one I created while by default I had the unreal class AIController